# the limit of $a_n=(-1)^n+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove by definition that the sequence
$$
a_n=(-1)^n+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}
$$
diverges. Inspired in another question found here, I thought this way: Suppose that $L$ is the limit of $(a_n)$. The statement 
$$
\forall\epsilon>0, \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}; \, n>n_0 \Rightarrow |a_n-L|<\epsilon.
$$
is false. Taking $\epsilon=1$, there would exist $n>n_0$ such that $|a_n-L|<1$ and is odd, but
\begin{eqnarray*}
|a_{n+1}-L| &=& |a_{n+1}-a_n+a_n-L| \\ 
    &=& \left|(-1)^{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}-(-1)^n-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+a_n-L\right| \\
    &=& \left| 2+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n}+a_n-L\right|>1
\end{eqnarray*}
so this $n$ does not exist.

What do you think?

Comment: In the first line of the computation you want $a_{n\color{red}{+1}}$ in the two places where you have $a_{n\color{red}{-1}}$, but otherwise it’s correct.

Comment: I typed wrongly.... I will correct it!

Answer (score 1):

It is right. Another method would be to assume that $a_n$ converges. We know that $b_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}n$ converges absolutely. Hence, the difference of these sequences should converge, which is oscillating giving rise to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to throw in another method here to illustrate a useful tool.

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to a limit $L$ if and only if every subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$.

Notice that the subsequence of even terms $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by $e_n := a_{2n}\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ converges to 
$$ e_n = a_{2n} =  1 + \frac{1}{2n} \to 1$$
whereas the sequence of odd terms $\{o_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by $o_n := a_{2n+1}\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ converges to 
$$ o_n = a_{2n+1} = -1 - \frac{1}{2n + 1} \to -1 $$

Thus, $\{a_n\}$ diverges.

Comment: Yes, but I had to use the definition of limit. Of course your solution is simpler.

Comment: A sequence converges iff its odd and even term subsequences converge to the same limit.